# How to remove inline style added to textarea by bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a textarea:

```
<textarea class="form-control" rows="1" style="overflow: hidden; word-wrap: break-word; resize: horizontal; height: 34px;"></textarea>
```

it's height is 34px in chrome, but in ie10 it's height is 14px.
I don't know how to remove its inline style, and who add the inline style to the textarea

Comment: Is that in-line you show added by you or already there? if its already there its some JS adding it in.

Comment: the inline style is added by js

Answer (score 2):

You can try using following commands:

```
document.getElementById("id").style.removeProperty('style-name');
```

Example:

```
document.getElementById("id").style.removeProperty('overflow');
```

where `"id"` is the id of element.

You can set property using

```
document.getElementById("id").style.color = 'red';
```

Comment: I want to control textarea height, textarea height is smaller in ie10 than chrome, I can just add inline style in textarea, like this: `<textarea style="height: 34px !important;"></textarea>`, but it's not well

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways, in preference of use:

- Remove the JS adding it to begin with.
- Override it in CSS using `!important;` (!important will override in-line)

```css
texarea {
      height: 34px !important;
    }
```

```html
<textarea class="form-control" rows="1" style="overflow: hidden; word-wrap: break-word; resize: horizontal; height: 34px;"></textarea>
```

- Finally remove it via js as in the answer provided by K K

Answer (score 2):

Its very simple

Add the below code inside script tag

```
$('textarea').removeAttr('style');
```

It removes entire style attribute from the tag, You might using from jquery pulgins , it might be adding the inline style

Or if you just want to remove height means use "!important" property for the "height" in css

In CSS

```
textarea{
 height:"auto!important"; // it overrides the inline style 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using [removeAttr()](https://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/) method.

```
$('textarea').removeAttr('style')
```

Comment: That would remove it from all textareas, and also remove all other styles, and there hardly seems to be a reason for bringing jQuery into the picture.

Comment: I agree, If we need to remove from particular textarea we can select with the help of this class -$('.form-control').